# Strange focus/click issues with Logitech MX1100R wireless mouse

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, mouse, bluetooth, logitech-mouse

This is a wireless mouse used with a (also wireless) Logitech diNovo Edge keyboard, which has a mouse (trackwheel + buttons) built in. Both use a (different) Logitech BT receiver widget and worked fine for years.

The mouse now has a problem that initially appeared to be a software problem. It seemed to start after a kernel upgrade (on Ubuntu 14.10), and behaved as if Unity/X/Compiz was not tracking focus/events properly. But now I also notice that it happens on Windows 8(.1).

Intermittently:

- mouse clicks seem to go through the foreground application into the desktop or application underneath
- wrong mouse button appears to be sent (e.g. right or middle-click instead of left-click)
- no highlight/interactivity on hover for controls (possibly due to the "through" problem)
- once the mouse starts misbehaving, it can also affect the keyboard's trackwheel/buttons
- switching to console (`Ctrl-Alt-F1`) and back seems to temporarily fix the problem
- switching the mouse off and on again seems to temporarily fix the problem

Sometimes it works fine for hours and then needs a reset every minute.

I find it very strange that switching consoles fixes the problem and that it affects the other mouse. I am starting to suspect some sort of hardware problem but looking for ideas for further investigation/potential fixes. I have tried multiple USB ports (front and back) for the BT receiver widget.

`xev` stops showing Motion/Focus events when it is not working properly but does not show anything like a stream of incorrect events.